# Is this a correct use of JSON-LD Index Maps?

Tags: json-ld

I want to create a collection of people in json-ld format but I need to keep some keys instead of using arrays so I tried this first:

```
{
  "@context" : {
    "@base" : "http://www.example.com/data/",
    "@vocab" : "http://www.example.com/vocab#",
    "name" : "schema:name",
    "people" : {
      "@container" : "@index",
      "@id" : "people"
    },
    "schema" : "http://schema.org/"
  },
  "@id" : "http://www.example.com",
  "people" : {
    "person1" : {
      "@id" : "people/person1",
      "name" : "Person 1"
    },
    "person2" : {
      "@id" : "people/person2",
      "name" : "Person 2"
    },
    "person3" : {
      "@id" : "people/person3",
      "name" : "Person 3"
    },
    "person4" : {
      "@id" : "people/person4",
      "name" : "Person 4"
    }
  }
}
```

Testing it in the JSON-LD Playground everything looks fine and the N-Quads result show something as expected like this:

```
<http://www.example.com/data/people/person1> <http://schema.org/name> "Person 1" .
<http://www.example.com/data/people/person2> <http://schema.org/name> "Person 2" .
<http://www.example.com/data/people/person3> <http://schema.org/name> "Person 3" .
<http://www.example.com/data/people/person4> <http://schema.org/name> "Person 4" .
<http://www.example.com> <http://www.example.com/vocab#people> <http://www.example.com/data/people/person1> .
<http://www.example.com> <http://www.example.com/vocab#people> <http://www.example.com/data/people/person2> .
<http://www.example.com> <http://www.example.com/vocab#people> <http://www.example.com/data/people/person3> .
<http://www.example.com> <http://www.example.com/vocab#people> <http://www.example.com/data/people/person4> .
```

Then I wanted to add a schema:knows property also keeping the keys and not using arrays like this:

```
{
  "@context" : {
    "@base" : "http://www.example.com/data/",
    "@vocab" : "http://www.example.com/vocab#",
    "knows" : {
      "@container" : "@index",
      "@id" : "schema:knows",
      "@type" : "@id"
    },
    "name" : "schema:name",
    "people" : {
      "@container" : "@index",
      "@id" : "people"
    },
    "schema" : "http://schema.org/"
  },
  "@id" : "http://www.example.com",
  "people" : {
    "person1" : {
      "@id" : "people/person1",
      "knows" : {
        "person2" : "people/person2",
        "person3" : "people/person3"
      },
      "name" : "Person 1"
    },
    "person2" : {
      "@id" : "people/person2",
      "name" : "Person 2"
    },
    "person3" : {
      "@id" : "people/person3",
      "name" : "Person 3"
    },
    "person4" : {
      "@id" : "people/person4",
      "name" : "Person 4"
    }
  }
}
```

This time when I tested in the playground it return the following error:

> { "name": "jsonld.SyntaxError", "message": "Invalid JSON-LD syntax;
>   conflicting @index property detected.", "details": { "code":
>   "conflicting indexes", "subject": { "@id":
>   "http://www.example.com/data/people/person2", "@index": "person2" } }
>   }

So what is an alternative to keep the keys and never use arrays or the correct way to use Index Maps?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct. You've discovered a bug in jsonld.js ([which I already reported](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/jsonld.js/issues/95)). You can try to run the example [in my playground](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/jsonld/playground/?json-ld=%7B%0A%20%20%22%40context%22%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22%40base%22%20%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fdata%2F%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22%40vocab%22%20%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fvocab%23%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22knows%22%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%40container%22%20%3A%20%22%40index%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%40id%22%20%3A%20%22schema%3Aknows%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%40type%22%20%3A%20%22%40id%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%20%3A%20%22schema%3Aname%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22people%22%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%40container%22%20%3A%20%22%40index%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%40id%22%20%3A%20%22people%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22schema%22%20%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%22%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22%40id%22%20%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%22%2C%0A%20%20%22people%22%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22person1%22%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%40id%22%20%3A%20%22people%2Fperson1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22knows%22%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22person2%22%20%3A%20%22people%2Fperson2%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22person3%22%20%3A%20%22people%2Fperson3%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%20%3A%20%22Person%201%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22person2%22%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%40id%22%20%3A%20%22people%2Fperson2%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%20%3A%20%22Person%202%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22person3%22%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%40id%22%20%3A%20%22people%2Fperson3%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%20%3A%20%22Person%203%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22person4%22%20%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%40id%22%20%3A%20%22people%2Fperson4%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%20%3A%20%22Person%204%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D&frame=%7B%7D&context=%7B%7D&startTab=tab-to_rdf) or by using [Gregg Kellogg's RDF distiller service](http://rdf.greggkellogg.net/distiller). Both return the triples you'd expect.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the error you encountered is due to the conflicting use of @index in the JSON-LD context. The @index keyword is used to define the index value for an index map, and it cannot be used for multiple properties in the same context. In your second example, you are trying to use @index for both "people" and "knows", which is causing the conflict.

To achieve your goal of keeping the keys and not using arrays, you can use the @container: @index pattern for properties that should be treated as index maps, and define them individually in the context. Here's how you can modify your JSON-LD to achieve this (it's just a suggestion, please don't take it wrong, your code it's really amazing):

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@base": "http://www.example.com/data/",
    "@vocab": "http://www.example.com/vocab#",
    "name": "schema:name",
    "person": "people",
    "knows": {
      "@container": "@index",
      "@id": "schema:knows",
      "@type": "@id"
    },
    "schema": "http://schema.org/"
  },
  "@id": "http://www.example.com",
  "people": {
    "person1": {
      "@id": "people/person1",
      "knows": {
        "person2": {
          "@id": "people/person2"
        },
        "person3": {
          "@id": "people/person3"
        }
      },
      "name": "Person 1"
    },
    "person2": {
      "@id": "people/person2",
      "name": "Person 2"
    },
    "person3": {
      "@id": "people/person3",
      "name": "Person 3"
    },
    "person4": {
      "@id": "people/person4",
      "name": "Person 4"
    }
  }
}
```

In this modified JSON-LD, we've defined the "knows" property as an index map using the @container: @index pattern, which allows us to keep the keys (person2 and person3) while specifying their values as objects containing @id properties.

With this approach, the JSON-LD Playground should parse the data without any conflicts, and you should get the desired N-Quads output. It will represent the relationships between people using index maps and still maintain the keys.

Hope this answers or help you! have an amazing day and thanks =)